# Is it possible to combine a subset of one excel file with data from another in Python?

Tags: python

I am extremely new to Python and am trying to understand how I might tackle this data management process.

I have one folder containing four files that are formatted like below:

```
    Plot_ID Band_1  Band_2  Band_3  Band_4  Band_5
0   1011    333.126140  1080.127438 238.625688  2339.344747 3223.257835
1   1012    329.561669  948.264767  230.246891  2157.999757 2991.620801
2   1021    330.972774  1053.827840 257.341779  2376.371536 3456.142320
3   1022    337.232824  958.765318  262.434414  2160.094638 3186.967143
4   1031    336.295936  1057.659725 257.727816  2407.085099 3509.672958
5   1032    335.780802  951.258131  261.304092  2140.353668 3212.060110
6   1041    331.297940  1043.316984 233.245706  2244.549355 3128.303351
7   1042    324.409074  900.391746  223.235948  1965.178680 2791.241491
```

Each file in the above folder is one of four dates.

I have another folder with a file that looks like below:

```
    plotid  y1  y2  y3  y4
0   1011    561.502920  887 493.157280  1.152
1   1021    597.242085  751 541.211220  1.156
2   1031    600.331215  738 544.173300  1.145
3   1041    585.983640  785 540.334575  1.163
```

Each 'y' column in this file is a response to be paired with data from the corresponding plot in the first set of files. Note that the first set of files has data that is arranged xxx1 or xxx2, whereas the second file only has xxx1. I do not need to use the xxx2 data here.

My end goal is to have a large dataset for each y that contains the Band_X values from each date, paired with a y for the corresponding plot. This is how the final data should begin to look:

```
   sample_id   y   X_1.000 X_2.000 X_3.000 X_4.000 X_5.000
0   10111   561.502920  333.126140  1080.127438 238.625688  2339.344747 3223.257835
1   10112   561.502920  91.346873   225.028589  68.981195   428.233010  684.843859
2   10113   561.502920  436.385469  947.656811  267.680206  1835.858824 2400.133395
3   10114   561.502920  482.958209  791.391684  255.482725  1142.655717 1764.903878
4   10211   597.242085  330.972774  1053.827840 257.341779  2376.371536 3456.142320
5   10212   597.242085  81.006132   219.288341  65.404662   409.077324  709.927136
6   10213   597.242085  390.487044  921.955848  264.171056  1887.662576 2648.249057
7   10214   597.242085  541.013308  945.007459  264.079985  1454.072436 2187.679130
```

Note that because each plot has four dates, I had to add a new number to the end of each plot.

How could I go about executing this? Any help at all would be enormously appreciated. I am fairly new to asking questions here, so if there is any reformatting to be done or additional information to be added, please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python as well and getting all the basic knowledge that I can so I at least know what is available to do. What you're asking about sounds, to me, like a perfect use of the pandas library for manipulating dataframes (for our purposes, spreadsheets). Using pandas you can read in each file and append to a single dataframe and then output only the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Don'FreihEitner'Eitner. Pandas seems like it'd be a good use here. Do you know if there is a way to join the two dataframes by only the rows that share a value for Plot_ID/plotid? Discarding the rows that have a Plot_ID that is not found in the second dataframe.

Comment: It appears there are several pandas methods for merging dataframes.  I don't think I can yet do justice to explaining them, but here are (if StackOverflow allows it) links to two helpful videos which not only discuss the options but show how they operate on real data.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9z3nHSnw0c&list=PLh4y833qAcMMRtNv-tj7rxaz378qeyfjs&index=1

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=788KHREDbX8